# How can I make this code simpler?

Tags: php

```
if(condition 1){
 var=changeVar(var);
 changed=true;
}

if(condition 2){
 var=changeVar2(var);
 changed=true;
}

if(condition 3){
 var=changeVar3(var);
 changed=true;
}
```

I don't like how `changed=true;` is repeated three times.

Comment: Frankly, your code is not that complicated.  But I would suggest you look at what all of your `changeVar()` functions do, since they all use `var` as an argument, maybe those functions can be merged?  Then you'd just have one function to call...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could save the old `var`, and compare it?

```
oldVar = var;

//your code here.

changed = (oldVar != var);
```

I had `==` in there at first, but wouldn't that give a wrong (or at least different) sollution then in the question?

Comment: This works if `changed` always is false before the code snippet.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed assuming that if the var isn't changed, it was false in the origional code.

Comment: this also assumes that `var` is not an object.  If it was, the object reference would make this not work how you expect it (it would never set `changed` to `true`)...

Comment: While typing this, I'd say there's a bug in here.. shouldn't it be `!=` when you've changed it? Anyway, when you don't change it, the reference would be the same (you didn't `clone` it), and when you let the `changeVar` return a new object, you  could get it to work with objects I think? But caution is needed ofcourse

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
if (condition 1) {
    var=changeVar(var);
}
if (condition 2) {
    var=changeVar2(var);
}
if (condition 3) {
    var=changeVar3(var);
}
changed=(condition 1||condition 2||condition 3||changed); // set changed value only if condition 1, condition 2 or condition 3 is true, keep old value otherwise
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (condition 1 || condition 2 || condition 3) {
    if (condition 1) {
        var = changeVar(var);
    }
    if (condition 2) {
        var = changeVar2(var);
    }
    if (condition 3) {
        var = changeVar3(var);
    }
    changed = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$changed = true;
if ($cond1) {}
elseif ($cond2) {}
else { $changed = false; }
```

Comment: and if `cond1` and `cond2` holds?

Comment: didn't think it was the case here, taking into account the change of the same variable in each separate condition. At any rate, the answer by **Nanne** is more elegant

Answer (score -1):

```
if(condition1||condition2||condition3) {
    switch(condition) {
        case 1: var = changeVar(var);
        break;
        case 2: var = changeVar2(var);
        break;
        case 3: var = changeVar3(var);
        break;
    }
    changed = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems to me that there is no `condition` in the question.